# Two Pandas Series replacement values using intermediate one

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

I'am new to Pandas, trying to use three Series like this ...

First one X :

```
DATE
2015-10-10 00:00:00      0.0
2015-10-10 01:00:00    290.0
2015-10-10 02:00:00    225.0
2015-10-10 03:00:00      4.0
2015-10-10 04:00:00      2.0
Name: X, dtype: bool
```

Second one S :

```
DATE
2015-10-10 00:00:00     True
2015-10-10 01:00:00    False
2015-10-10 02:00:00    False
2015-10-10 03:00:00     True
2015-10-10 04:00:00     True
Name: S, dtype: bool
```

Third one Average :

```
DATE
2015-10-10 00:00:00      0.000000
2015-10-10 01:00:00    145.000000
2015-10-10 02:00:00    171.666667
2015-10-10 03:00:00    128.750000
2015-10-10 04:00:00    103.000000
Name: average, dtype: bool
```

What I want to do is : 
replace values in X with the corresponding values by index in Average if it is True in S.
What is the best and more efficient way to do that ?

Comment: I think `X = Average.where(S == True)` should work

Comment: @EdChum it did work, but it replaces values in X if it is False in S by NaN !

Comment: See my answer, you can pass `X` as another arg which it will default to when it's `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) passing in the `Series` to test against:

```
In [231]:
Average.where(S==True, X)

Out[231]:
DATE
2015-10-10 00:00:00      0.00
2015-10-10 01:00:00    290.00
2015-10-10 02:00:00    225.00
2015-10-10 03:00:00    128.75
2015-10-10 04:00:00    103.00
Name: val, dtype: float64
```